# Firebase ID token - JWT::VerificationError Exception: Signature verification raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-signin

Validating the firebase id token in ruby on rails with library ***"firebase_id_token"***.

Once I got the valid token from the front-end with the ***google_sign_in*** library and sending it to the backend, it always prompts as **"JWT::VerificationError (Signature verification raised)"**. Even though I have checked in jwt.io, where I could able see the information of payload and header but unable to verfiy the signature.

*firebase_id_token.rb*

```rb
FirebaseIdToken.configure do |config|
  config.project_ids = ["project_id"]
  config.redis = Redis.new(host: "localhost", port: 6379)
end

FirebaseIdToken::Certificates.request
```

Also, I checked the `kid` key is a valid one on this link
https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

I have been debugging the code for more than a week, Please anyone assist with this issue.

**PS:** I have tested the code with a valid token and not an expired one.

Comment: Leaving Note:
The issue is with the token creation part in the frontend, once we altered the code it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google sign-in returns an OAuth2 token, not a JWT as far as I know, and definitely *not* a Firebase ID token. If you are passing this Google sign-in token to your backend code, it correctly gets rejected when you try to verify it as a Firebase ID token.

To get a Firebase ID token, you need to sign-in to Firebase with the Google sign-in token (by calling `signInWithCredential`) and then pass the resulting Firebase ID token to your backend code.

Comment: I will provide the header value from the token. It states that the type is **JWT**

`{"alg": "RS256","kid": "2cdabd2075c84142446713e3e44e9d718e7c2db4","typ": "JWT"}`


Also, I'm sure the token is a Firebase Id token, Because in the payload I have this key-value pair.

`"firebase": {"identities": {"google.com": ["106342823030713405321"],"email": ["humantorch@gmail.com"]}`